# Sort a multi-dimensional array in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays

Bit of a setup here to explain my issue, but in theory, all I need to do is order a multi-dimensional array before it outputs. The issue I'm having is that it's not grouping all the As, Bs and Cs etc together. I think it needs to sort all the names, before it adds the first letter...

```
<?php query_posts ( array ( 
    'post_type' => 'programme',
    'category_name' => 'archive',
    'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>

<div class="container_12">
    <div class="prefix_1 grid_10 suffix_1">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php 

            $groups = array();

            if ( have_rows('artists') ) {

                while ( have_rows('artists') ) {

                    the_row();


                    // vars
                    $first_name = get_sub_field('first_name');
                    $last_name = get_sub_field('last_name');
                    $first_letter = substr($last_name, 0, 1);


                    // add $first_letter holder to groups
                    if( !isset($groups[ $first_letter ]) ) {

                        $groups[ $first_letter ] = array();

                    }


                    // append artist to group
                    $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;

                }

            }

            // ouput
            if( !empty($groups) ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $groups as $letter => $artists ) : ?>

                    <h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3>

                    <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ): ?>
                        <p><?php echo $artist; ?></p>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This currently outputs as:

[image]

And if you see in the image below, where I have just print_r( $groups ) it needs to add all the arrays into one big array, then sort it.

[image]

So, ultimately, I'd like to end up with something like:

```
A
Joe Allan
Frank Aztec

B
Jane Bank

C
Mike Crichton
Mandy Curtz
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I have no, and need to sort the artists, alphabetically, by their last name.

```
<?php if( !empty($groups) ) : ?>
    <?php ksort($groups); ?>
    <?php foreach ( $groups as $letter => $artists ) : ?>
        <div>
        <h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3>
        <?php asort($artists); ?>
        <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $artist; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This gives me, using **B** as an example:

```
B

Berendes, Eva

Bloor, Simon

Bloor, Tom

Burt, Theo

Barnes, Kristian

Bajo, Elena
```

Comment: You are creating a new `$groups` array in each while loop iteration, and you are making the output inside your loop as well – if you actually want to list the artists of _all_ posts in _one_ list in the end, then of course you have to initialize the array _outside_ of the loop, and also make the output _after_ the loop.

Comment: I wanted to propose you a different solution to what IMHO is the real problem: Show ordered data from WP, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose a totally different approach to the problem. I know it's not the answer to the exact question you post, but I think it's the answer to your problem. I believe your problem is getting the array of artists with the capital letter, so, instead of doing all this PHP nightmare, I would like to propose you get all ordered via MySQL from the DDBB (because ordering via PHP is hard, complex (as you are just watching) and resourcing hog...) and only print the results:

```
<?php
    // Get access to DDBB manager object
    global $wpdb;

    // Launch a query will give back all ordered, in rows with the capital letter
    // and an array in JSON format with the group names
    $query = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT('[', CONCAT(first_name, ', ',last_name), ']' SEPARATOR ', ') as name
, LEFT(last_name, 1) capLetter
FROM artists 
GROUP BY capLetter
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;");

    // Printing the results (they came ordered, ;D):
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        echo $row->capLetter;
        $artists = json_decode($row->name);
        foreach ($artists as $artist) {
            echo $artist;
        }
    }    

?>
```

I use GROUP_CONCAT to build a JSON array in which we store the values from the DDBB, and with group and order from the MySQL engine is pretty easy to achieve what we want. I only tested the query, and I got the way of launching a custom query with WordPress from http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/working-custom-database-tables-wordpress/

Comment: @wtfzdotnet, read this, XD: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Put  `$groups = array();` above the first while loop, and also:

```
    if( !empty($groups) ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $groups as $letter => $artists ) : ?>

            <h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3>

            <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ): ?>
                <p><?php echo $artist; ?></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

below the `<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Thank you so much. So, this gives me: http://cl.ly/image/2k212w1S191Q/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-21%20at%2014.10.08.png so is there a way to short the A, B, C etc in order, but also by `last_name` ?

Comment: For sorting the starting letters you could use `ksort` (http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Ordering by `last_name` could be more diffult, because you are concatenating two string there.  If you switch the names like `last_name . first_name` you could use `asort` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Comment: I've got it to sort the starting letters, using ksort as you suggested. But yes, last_name is more difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Like how Chococroc proposed , achieving it using a database query would be efficient .

But if you were already running a query for some other purpose which also retrieves the artists , then rather than running another query , you could use PHP based solution .

Assuming that you can grab all the names , I am considering an input array like this :

```
$allNames =
    array(
        array( 'Kate' ,'Allen' )
        ,array( 'Simon' ,'Bloor' )
        ,array( 'Tom' ,'Bloor' )
        ,array( 'Theo' ,'Burt' )
        ,array( 'Ross' ,'Chisholm' )
        ,array( 'Eva' ,'Berendes' )
        ,array( 'Kristian' ,'Barnes' )
        ,array( 'Ashley' ,'Holmes' )
        ,array( 'Joe' ,'Allan' )
        ,array( 'Frank' ,'Aztec' )
        ,array( 'Jane' ,'Bank' )
        ,array( 'Kike' ,'Crichton' )
        ,array( 'Mandy' ,'Curtz' )
    );
```

The actual solution starts here :

```
/*
 *  Put all the names in to $tempArray as lastName:firstName format
 */

$tempArray = array();

foreach( $allNames as $fullName )
{
    list( $firstName ,$lastName ) = $fullName;
    $tempArray[] = $lastName .':' .$firstName; 
}

/*
 *  Use which ever sort suits your requirement and sort the $tempArray
 */

sort( $tempArray );

/*
 *  Now put the names into groups by the first letter of last name
 */

$groups = array( );

foreach( $tempArray as $value )
{
    $firstLetter = substr( $value ,0 ,1 );

    if( ! isset( $groups[$firstLetter] ) ) $groups[$firstLetter] = array( );

    list( $lastName ,$firstName ) = explode( ":" ,$value );

    $groups[$firstLetter][] = $firstName .' ' .$lastName;
}
```

Result :

```
var_dump( $groups );
```

Gives :

```
  'A' => 
      'Joe Allan'
      'Kate Allen'
      'Frank Aztec'
  'B' => 
      'Jane Bank'
      'Kristian Barnes'
      'Eva Berendes'
      'Simon Bloor'
      'Tom Bloor'
      'Theo Burt'
  'C' => 
      'Ross Chisholm'
      'Kike Crichton'
      'Mandy Curtz'
  'H' => 
      'Ashley Holmes'
```

> If I were to include my solution in to the code you've tried , it could turn to as shown below . This is not tested and probably could need modifications :

```
<?php query_posts ( array (
    'post_type' => 'programme',
    'category_name' => 'archive',
    'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>

<div class="container_12">
    <div class="prefix_1 grid_10 suffix_1">
        <?php
        /*
         *  Put all the names in to $tempArray as lastName:firstName format
         */
        $tempArray = array();
        ?>

        <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php 
            if( have_rows( 'artists' ) )
            {
                while( have_rows('artists') )
                {
                    the_row();
                    $tempArray[] = get_sub_field( 'last_name' ) .':' .get_sub_field( 'first_name' );
                }
            }
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php
        /*
         *  Use which ever sort suits your requirement and sort the $tempArray
         */

        sort( $tempArray );

        /*
         *  Now put the names into groups by the first letter of last name
         */

        $groups = array( );

        foreach( $tempArray as $value )
        {
            $firstLetter = substr( $value ,0 ,1 );

            if( ! isset( $groups[$firstLetter] ) ) $groups[$firstLetter] = array( );

            list( $lastName ,$firstName ) = explode( ":" ,$value );

            $groups[$firstLetter][] = $firstName .' ' .$lastName;
        }
        ?>

        <?php if( ! empty($groups) ): ?>

            <?php foreach( $groups as $letter => $artists ) : ?>

                <h3><?php echo $letter; ?></h3>

                <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ): ?>
                    <p><?php echo $artist; ?></p>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the author got another problem with sorting the array i will add another answer which hopefully does help.
As stated in my comment you should use `ksort` to sort the outer array by key. 
Now sorting the inner arrays by the last name is a little bit trickier.
There is a useful function called `uasort`, which lets the user define a function by which the array entries are getting compared.
So what you want to do is something like this:

```
ksort($groups);
foreach ($groups as &$group) {
    uasort($group, 'sortLastName');
}
unset($group);
```

While using `sortLastName` as a comparison function, which is defined like this:

```
function sortLastName($a, $b) {
    $aLast = end(explode(" ", $a));
    $bLast = end(explode(" ", $b));

    return strcasecmp($aLast, $bLast);
};
```

Here is a working example on Ideone.com
http://ideone.com/vU8ukk

Hope i could help you.

Comment: Hi @puelo. Many thanks. If I went with `last_name . first_name` like you suggested, and add `asort` to `$artists` it still doesn't seem to sort it properly? Updated my original question with my code.

Comment: The sorting part seems to be missing in the code of your original question.

Comment: `<?php asort($artists); ?>` ??

Comment: Are you doing this inside your `foreach` loop (`<?php foreach( $groups as $letter => $artists ) : ?>`)? You can also use `sort`. The difference is that asort maintains the correlation between the key and the value, which is not needed here.

Comment: Oh i forgot to add. You need to use the reference of `$artists` like this: `foreach($groups as $letter => &$artists) {` otherwise the changes inside the loop won't persist.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I've added sort($artists) but it still doesn't sort them as your code does... http://snippi.com/s/14ox0cx